# Back in iOS 6, updating an app with 10s of 1000s of local files took hours because of the sandbox transfer

Tags: ios, objective-c, sandbox

In more detail, last time I tried releasing updates of my app when it had thousands of files in local storage took hours because the iPad had to transfer the sandboxed files in the app's private directory over to the new app. The time required was proportional to the number of files, not the amount of data in the files. So as a workaround I built my app around a small number of very large database files, Core Data in some cases and sqlite databases in other cases. Unfortunately, the time required to store the data in those databases is also huge and swamps the network transfer time of the raw data.

Now in iOS 8 is there a way to store a large tree of directories (5+ gigabytes of data) external to the app so that it doesn't have to be copied every time the app is updated?

Comment: Why would you have an app with tens of thousands of files?

Comment: The app is an aviation database that must work untethered. The maps are broken into about 500 thousand 256x256 jpeg tiles, representing various maps and various zoom levels in the google maps projection. The iPad needs all the tiles.

Comment: It's very inefficient to put them in individual files.

Comment: (Note that you can simply put them in a zip file, and unzip the individual elements as you need them, allowing you to maintain your existing file structure.  In fact, the "bundle" is effectively a zip file, so you should be able to access them from there vs having to move them to the app private directory, if you don't want to maintain an ability to update them.)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use iCloud storage.